# Remote Apache Ignite cluster connection failures

Tags: ignite

I can successfully join and leave a single node Apache Ignite 2.8.1 topology running as Docker container on my local Docker server.

Running the exact same program but on a remote Docker server I can see my program joining the cluster topology but before the connection completes I am getting the following connection error

```
SEVERE: Failed to send message to remote node [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=a239f009-bddd-4a06-845f-abb304850849, consistentId=127.0.0.1,172.17.0.13:42002, addrs=ArrayList [127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.13], sockAddrs=HashSet [/172.17.0.13:42002, /127.0.0.1:42002], discPort=42002, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1605015503009, loc=false, ver=2.8.1#20200521-sha1:86422096, isClient=false], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=null, partCntrs=null, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=true, exchangeStartTime=106333448635300, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=dc9a3700-5377-4095-ac2b-31a2cea3d9a5, consistentId=dc9a3700-5377-4095-ac2b-31a2cea3d9a5, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.91.7.30, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.81, 192.168.38.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [host.docker.internal/192.168.1.81:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, GBLG7Y7GH2.mshome.net/192.168.38.1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, GBLG7Y7GH2.enterprisenet.org/10.91.7.30:0], discPort=0, order=2, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1605015498538, loc=true, ver=2.8.1#20200521-sha1:86422096, isClient=true], topVer=2, nodeId8=dc9a3700, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1605015505481], nodeId=dc9a3700, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1605015496511, nodeOrder=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, lastAffChangedTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], err=null, skipPrepare=false]]]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=a239f009-bddd-4a06-845f-abb304850849, addrs=[/172.17.0.13:42003, /127.0.0.1:42003]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3738)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3458)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createCommunicationClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3198)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3078)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2918)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2877)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2035)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2132)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1257)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.sendLocalPartitions(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:2020)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.clientOnlyExchange(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1436)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:903)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3214)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3063)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=a239f009-bddd-4a06-845f-abb304850849, addrs=[/172.17.0.13:42003, /127.0.0.1:42003]]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3740)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:129)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3584)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:129)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3584)
    ... 15 more
```

In my view the problem relates to the client connection settings, so I tried to increase the client discovery SPI "joinTimeout", "networkTimeout" and "socketTimeout" settings as well as the "connectionTimeout" and "socketWriteTimeout" settings but without success.

Comment: It seems that the client node a239f009-bddd-4a06-845f-abb304850849 is not reachable by communication SPI. What configuration do you have for the communication? Do you have communication port correctly mapeed in Docker?

Comment: Yes, all ports are mapped in remote Docker.

But, I think I have figured this out.

It seems this is rather an impossible scenario as my remote Docker server runs on a public VPS and communication SPI cannot bind itself to the public IP of my VPS.

Therefore, the client successfully discovers the cluster but then tries to talk to the communication SPI on the address that it is bound which is not the public internet IP of the VPS the Docker server is running under.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set up an `AddressResolver` for the node running inside the remote Docker container.

Have a look at: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/aws/manual-install-on-ec2#connecting-a-client-node

If you're using Spring configuration, then your config should look something like that:

```
    <property name="addressResolver">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BasicAddressResolver">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="172.31.59.27" value="3.93.186.198"/>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <!-- other properties -->

    <!-- Discovery configuration -->
</bean>
```

Here 172.31.59.27 is an inner IP and 3.93.186.198 is an external IP, that you're connecting to.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that an AddressResolver would be required, but, I didn't know how to use one.
I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Did you open 47500 and 45100 ports both way between your Docker and remote node?

Comment: I am using ports 42002 for discovery and 42003 for communication.
Both ports are accessible by client machine.
However, I fear the communication SPI on the remote Docker can only bind itself to its local address and not the public IP address visible to the client.
This is I fear the reason why the same experiment works when running on a local Docker server.
The client successfully discovers the cluster but then tries to talk to the communication SPI on the address that it is bound which is not the public internet IP of the remote Docker server which is the only one visible to the client.

Comment: Aren't there some switches to Docker to change its binding behavior?

Comment: I knew it wouldn't work but I have tried binding the Ignite Docker container's commnication port to the public IP of the Docker server. It didn't work.
The remote Ignite client node negotiates discovery successfully but then the remote Ignite server node seems to be sending back the coordinates of its communication port which are not accessible from a remote network.
All of this sounds correct I am afraid and as per Ignite design.
I am not aware of any kind of Docker settings that would allow such an peculiar kind of binding :-)
I believe the problem lies with Ignite comm protocols.

Comment: You can set `localAddress` in `TcpCommunicationSpi` configuration to specify the correct address.

Comment: Sadly, like I said, I did this even though I knew it wouldn't work and it didn't.
I used the public internet IP of the Docker server and I got a binding error.
I feel more and more that Ignite communications protocol was designed for private networks only.